# Naming Convention for Open-EJB embedded container?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, apache-tomee, openejb

I'm using `open-ejb` embedded container to write tests for a javaee application. The app contains just one `@Stateless` bean and test

```
import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ProductDaoTest {

    private EJBContainer container;

    @Before
    public void initializeContainerAndDatabase(){
        container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
        System.out.println(container);
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){

    }
}
```

For some reasons the success or failure of the embedded container getting started is determined by the folder name in which the source code is put. I tried different names, in some it worked, In some it didn't and the pattern seems random to me.

> hibernate-javaee --> didn't work
>   hibernate-ejb --> didn't work
>   javaee-hibernate --> didn't work
>   abc-xyz --> worked
>   hibernate-abc-xyz-def --> didn't work
>   abc-xyz-def-ejb --> didn't work
>   abc-xyz-def-javaee --> worked
>   abc-xyz-def-hibernate --> worked

In case of failure the exception trace is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.ares.hibernate.javaee.dao.ProductDaoTest
INFO - ********************************************************************************
INFO - OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
INFO - Startup: Wed Jun 08 08:57:56 IST 2016
INFO - Copyright 1999-2015 (C) Apache OpenEJB/TomEE Project, All Rights Reserved.
INFO - Version: 4.7.4
INFO - Build date: 20160304
INFO - Build time: 09:05
INFO - ********************************************************************************
INFO - openejb.home = C:\fakepath\hibernate-abc-xyz-def
INFO - openejb.base = C:\fakepath\hibernate-abc-xyz-def
INFO - Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@26f67b76
INFO - Succeeded in installing singleton service
INFO - Using 'javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer=true'
INFO - Cannot find the configuration file [conf/openejb.xml].  Will attempt to create one for the beans deployed.
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Default Security Service)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
INFO - Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
INFO - Creating SecurityService(id=Default Security Service)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.039 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(org.ares.hibernate.javaee.dao.ProductDaoTest)  Time elapsed: 1.81 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$NoModulesFoundException: No modules found to deploy.
1)Maybe descriptors are placed in incorrect location.
Descriptors could go under:
<base-dir>/META-INF or <base-dir>/WEB-INF
but not directly under <base-dir>
Check 'Application Discovery via the Classpath' docs page for more info
2)Maybe no modules are present in the classpath.
Is 'openejb.base' system property pointing to the intended location?
        at org.apache.openejb.util.Exceptions.newNoModulesFoundException(Exceptions.java:99)
        at org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$Provider.load(OpenEjbContainer.java:540)
        at org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$Provider.createEJBContainer(OpenEjbContainer.java:322)
        at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:56)
        at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:43)
        at org.ares.hibernate.javaee.dao.ProductDaoTest.initializeContainerAndDatabase(ProductDaoTest.java:14)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Tests in error:
  test(org.ares.hibernate.javaee.dao.ProductDaoTest): No modules found to deploy.(..)
```

In case of success, the output is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.ares.hibernate.javaee.dao.ProductDaoTest
INFO - ********************************************************************************
INFO - OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
INFO - Startup: Wed Jun 08 09:07:02 IST 2016
INFO - Copyright 1999-2015 (C) Apache OpenEJB/TomEE Project, All Rights Reserved.
INFO - Version: 4.7.4
INFO - Build date: 20160304
INFO - Build time: 09:05
INFO - ********************************************************************************
INFO - openejb.home = C:\fakepath\abc-xyz-def-hibernate
INFO - openejb.base = C:\fakepath\abc-xyz-def-hibernate
INFO - Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@26f67b76
INFO - Succeeded in installing singleton service
INFO - Using 'javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer=true'
INFO - Cannot find the configuration file [conf/openejb.xml].  Will attempt to create one for the beans deployed.
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Default Security Service)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
INFO - Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
INFO - Creating SecurityService(id=Default Security Service)
INFO - Found EjbModule in classpath: c:\fakepath\abc-xyz-def-hibernate\target\classes
INFO - Beginning load: c:\fakepath\abc-xyz-def-hibernate\target\classes
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: C:\fakepath\abc-xyz-def-hibernate
INFO - Auto-deploying ejb ProductDao: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=ProductDao)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Stateless Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateless Container)
INFO - Auto-creating a container for bean ProductDao: Container(type=STATELESS, id=Default Stateless Container)
INFO - Creating Container(id=Default Stateless Container)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Managed Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Managed Container)
INFO - Auto-creating a container for bean org.ares.hibernate.javaee.dao.ProductDaoTest: Container(type=MANAGED, id=Default Managed Container)
INFO - Creating Container(id=Default Managed Container)
INFO - Using directory C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp for stateful session passivation
INFO - Enterprise application "C:\fakepath\abc-xyz-def-hibernate" loaded.
INFO - Assembling app: C:\fakepath\abc-xyz-def-hibernate
INFO - Jndi(name="java:global/abc-xyz-def-hibernate/ProductDao!org.ares.hibernate.javaee.dao.ProductDao")
INFO - Jndi(name="java:global/abc-xyz-def-hibernate/ProductDao")
INFO - Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@26f67b76
INFO - OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
INFO - Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
INFO - Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
INFO - All injection points were validated successfully.
INFO - OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 195 ms.
INFO - Created Ejb(deployment-id=ProductDao, ejb-name=ProductDao, container=Default Stateless Container)
INFO - Started Ejb(deployment-id=ProductDao, ejb-name=ProductDao, container=Default Stateless Container)
INFO - Deployed Application(path=C:\fakepath\abc-xyz-def-hibernate)
org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer@34c01041
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.224 sec
```

To make sure that the session bean is getting discovered in classpath I've added

```
Enumeration<URL> ejbJars = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("org/ares/hibernate/javaee/dao/ProductDao.class");
        while (ejbJars.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL url = ejbJars.nextElement();
            System.out.println("app = " + url);
        }
```

as mentioned in [this link](http://openejb.apache.org/application-discovery-via-the-classpath.html). The class is getting discovered in both working and non working cases.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.ares.hibernate.javaee.dao.ProductDaoTest
app = file:/C:/fakepath/hibernate-ejb/target/classes/org/ares/hibernate/javaee/dao/ProductDao.class
```

Is there a naming convention for this that I dont't know about or did I stumble upon a bug?

The source code for the application is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1PCWH2ykvSBeDY5SHdETTZNYjA/view?usp=sharing). The parent directory for the project is `abc-def` and while running `mvn clean test` the project runs. If the parent directory name is changed to `hibernate-javaee` and the application stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some [patterns](https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/master/container/openejb-core/src/main/resources/default.exclusions) are automatically excluded from OpenEJB scanning.

Comment: Indeed both `javaee-` and `hibernate-` are in the exclusion list.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the naming convention question, there is none. I am pretty sure that you somewhere (system properties file or programmatically) excluding/including paths. Excluding/Including allows wildcard usages that's why some folder patterns work and some none. To exclude nothing and include all create your EJB container with the following properties.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude", "");
p.put("openejb.deployments.classpath.include", ".*");
container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p);
```

See http://tomee.apache.org/application-discovery-via-the-classpath.html for further instructions.

Other options to make sure your `EJB` will be deployed.

Option 1: Application discovery

If you don't want to add an additional configuration file you have to make sure that your EJB folder is part of the classpath and your EJB contains a `ejb-jar.xml`. See http://tomee.apache.org/application-discovery-via-the-classpath.html for further instructions.

Option 2: Configuration file

According to the log you didn't have configured a configuration file.

```
INFO - Cannot find the configuration file [conf/openejb.xml].  Will attempt to create one for the beans deployed.
```

In most cases this is fine and a custom configuration file is the exception. Try to set the configuration file with you folder settings. See http://openejb.apache.org/configuration.html for further instructions.

Comment: For the second part of your answer, as per [open-ejb documentation](http://tomee.apache.org/embedded-configuration.html), `OpenEJB will function fine with no configuration at all and will happily create things as needed and select defaults for everything. So in a real sense configuration is all about overriding those defaults.` I'm not overriding any defaults for both the working and non-working scenario. I'll check the link you gave in first part of your answer.

Comment: Checked the link for application discovery, there is nothing related to wildcards. It is working with just some changes in directory name and driving me insane.

Comment: @ares, Please post your system properties file. You can find the file in conf/system.properties. And check if an additional user system.properties file exist in ${user.home}/.openejb/system.properties.

Comment: I'm using an embedded container with the dependency `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomee-embedded</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>`. Hence I dont't have a `conf/system.properties`. Also  I don't have a `${user.home}/.openejb/system.properties`

Comment: Okay, your test class is in the classpath and it contains a ejb-jar.xml?

Comment: Yes the test class is in the  classpath and it didn't initially contain `ejb-jar.xml`. I added `ejb-jar.xml` and still the same problem. I've added some more info in the question. Also, I really appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: @ares, try to configure your ejb container to exclude nothing and include all. See my edited answer for details.

Comment: I did add inclusions and exclusions but the problem still remains.

Comment: @ares, do you get the embedded tomee artifact direct from the maven repository? Or do you have a company repository?

Comment: Directly from the maven repository. I have mentioned the group and artifact id. I also tried open ejb 5 but it has the same issue. I'll put the compete code on gist so that it can be tested else where.

Comment: @ares, good idea. What you can also try is to remove the artifact from your local maven repository (.m2 folder) and download it again.

Comment: I've linked the source code so that you can try yourself. Also a point to note that I'm on windows  OS.

Answer (score 0):

Note that openejb.additional.include=myjarprefix can allow you to add it back in the scan inclusions. It will remove the conflicting excludes so make it the longer as possible if you use it. It can be set in conf/system.properties.